# Independent zero-mean random variables maximum inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d . zero-mean random variables with symmetric PDF's and $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i.$ Rhen for any $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\mathbb{P}(\max_{1\leq k\leq n} S_k>\varepsilon) \leq 2 \mathbb{P}(S_n>\varepsilon)
$$
I can just observe that these PDF's has to be symmetric around mean, thus around zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\epsilon > 0$ and $S_0 := 0$.  By symmetry, the proof will be the same for $-\epsilon$.  The idea is to break up $\{S_n > \epsilon\}$ into disjoint events when $S_k$ first passes $\epsilon$.  Define the events
$$
A_k := \{S_k > \epsilon,\ S_i \le \epsilon\ \forall i < k\}
$$
which are the disjoint events that $k$ is the first time we exceed $\epsilon$.  Notice that
$$
P(\max_{1\le k \le n} S_k > \epsilon) = \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k)
$$
since the maximum exceeds $\epsilon$ if and only if at least one of the $S_k$ exceeds $\epsilon$ by time $n$.  Since we want to stay above $\epsilon$ at the final time, multiply both sides by $P(S_n - S_k \ge 0)$.  By symmetry, $P(S_n - S_k \ge 0) \ge 1/2$, so
$$
\frac{1}{2}P(\max_{1\le k \le n} S_k > \epsilon) \le \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k)P(S_n - S_k \ge 0)
$$
$S_n - S_k$ depends only on $X_{k+1},\ldots,X_n$, while $A_k$ depends only on $X_1,\ldots,X_k$.  The $X_i$ are i.i.d. so in fact
$$
P(A_k)P(S_n - S_k \ge 0) = P(A_k \cap \{S_n - S_k \ge 0\}) = P(S_k > \epsilon,\ S_i \le \epsilon\ \forall i < k,\ S_n - S_k \ge 0)
$$
If $S_k > \epsilon$ and $S_n-S_k \ge 0$, then $S_n > \epsilon$.  Moreover, $A_k \cap \{S_n - S_k \ge 0\}$ are still disjoint sets.  Thus,
$$
\frac{1}{2}P(\max_{1\le k \le n} S_k > \epsilon) \le \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k \cap \{S_n - S_k \ge 0\})
 \le P(S_n > \epsilon)
$$
and therefore, $P(\max_{1\le k \le n}S_k > \epsilon) \le 2P(S_n > \epsilon)$.  Note that this proof does not require existence of a PDF.